# Trouble calling function after Infinite Scroll runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Infinite Scroll plugin, for Wordpress, to load new posts on to the page when users scroll to the bottom. The problem is this has been loading duplicate posts, as the sorting changes extremely fast (due to popularity) and posts end up on different pages.

When the plugin grabs the next page, sometimes products that were originally on the FIRST page have been sorted to the SECOND page. So I end up with duplicates.

I was planning on waiting for the script to load the next page content, then loop through all of the post titles and locate the duplicates. Then I would remove the second instance of each post.

I noticed Infinite Scroll has a window in the settings labeled "Run after content is loaded/callback" so I thought I could enter a function in that field to be called.

```js
removeDuplicates();
```

Then I entered something like this in the footer:

```js
function removeDuplicates(){
  var titleList = [];
  $('.title').each(function(i, obj) {

      /* The titles are in <h1> tags, I cycle through them, 
     if it's the first time seeing the title I add it to titleList. 
     If it's already in the array I hide the parent. */
      
  });
});
```

I keep getting "undefined function" related to the .each, and it seems like it has something to do with scope but I'm not sure what's happening.

Is there an easier way to trigger the function to remove the duplicates? Am I at least on the right track?

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like jquery isn't loaded. Even if you use a selector that returns no elements, it should still have the `.each()` method.

Try using vanillaJS instead of jquery.

```
var titleNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.title'); // get elements
var titleElArray = Array.prototype.slice(titleNodeList); // convert to array
titleElArray.forEach(function(el){...}); // iterate
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, but it's still not working unfortunately. I see this comment in the code, referring to the callback box: "previously, we would pass in the new DOM element as context for the callback however we're now using a documentfragment, which doesn't have parents or children, so the context is the contentContainer guy, and we pass in an array of the elements collected as the first argument.

Comment: The selector won't work if the element isn't in the document yet. Instead of `document.querySelectorAll()`, you need to call `theDocumentFragment.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Your original answer actually ended up pretty much doing it. I had to use titleNodeList.length, then run a for loop against that number doing something like titleNodeList[x].innerHTML. Thank you!